# Form redirect on submit not working, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code on my search form:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="www.test.gr" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
     onsubmit="window.location.href='www.test.gr/search/document.getElementById('location').value';  
             return false;">
```

But it is not working. Maybe the quotes are wrong inside `document.getElementById`.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should concat string with object value. In your case `document.getElementById('location').value` statement is interpreted as a part of a string.

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="www.test.gr" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="window.location.href = 'www.test.gr/search/' + document.getElementById('location').value;  return false;">
```

Comment: You should add an explanation.

Comment: so easy! there is no need for explanation... thank you a lot. i will accept your answer after 10 minutes